# Cross Product: is there an inverse?

Tags: cross-product

I learning vector calculus and electromagnetism, from which I noticed cross product is used extensively.  I.e. $\phi = \Delta \times \mathbf E$.  I'm curious, is there an inverse to the cross product?  It seems that for two vectors it would be a plane and for the case of $\phi$ above maybe some integral?  My goal is solving for different variables in these equations and am curious if such an operation is used.

Comment: The definition of "inverse" presupposes that there's an identity element.  But there is no identity element for the cross-product.

Comment: @AndreasBlass In this context, I believe the question is whether or not we can recover the two vectors used to obtain the cross product.

Comment: The question seems to be asking something different than it shows. I have a feeling the original question was meant to be if there's an inverse to the curl.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inverse for the cross product. To see why, consider two vectors $A$ and $B$. The cross product is $|A||B|\sin{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them. You can rotate each of those vectors to a different position maintaining the angle between them. Since their magnitudes don't change in a rotation and we have preserved the angle between them, we get the same cross product.

Edit:
As @Andrei points out in his comment, the rotation of $A$ and $B$ must be about $A\times B$ to preserve the cross product.

Comment: In addition, if the rotation is around the $A\times B$ vector, then the direction of the cross product is also preserved (otherwise is just the magnitude).

Comment: So, by your description, cross product is not an bijection, which implies there is no inverse of the function?

Comment: Yes, to both comments. The rotation is around the $A\times B$ vector because we are preserving the cross product and the cross product is not a bijection so it has no inverse.

Comment: Not only can you rotate them, but you can also do things like multiply $A$ by $3$ and $B$ by $1/3$.

Comment: Although $A \times B$ can't be inverted alone, it's worth noting that if you know $A$ and $A \cdot B$ as well, that's enough to uniquely reconstruct $B$. You can see this as being the inverse of the geometric product in geometric algebra.